# Android: replace existing apk if exists

Tags: android, download, apk, download-manager

I am downloading an Android application to the path: `/mnt/sdcard/download/App.apk` using the `DownloadManager` class. If the App.apk already exists, the download fails. How to replace the existing apk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DownloadManager` will not let you do this. You should delete or rename the existing file first.

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/download/App.apk");
if (f.exists()) { 
    f.delete();
    // or
    f.renameTo(...);
}
```

Comment: How to check if the file already exists in order to delete it?